# ASN.1 compilers

Tags: c, protocols, asn.1

This is my first question so please bear with me, I'm trying to find a good compiler to parse the following [standard](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/29_series/29.002/ASN.1/), I've tried asn1c and I wasn't able compile it successfully, the problem is that I didn't get any error, I tried with "-P" and there was no output, this is what I did

sn1c MAP-ShortMessageServiceOperations.EXP -P

The files in the link have been generated by SIEMENS and for some reason they are not the standard ASN.1

The question is how can I compile all these ASN files with asn1c or any other asn compiler?

and also I've tried snacc and didn't get anything useful from it either.

I'm trying to write a C application that will be running on Red-hat Linux

Comment: This is just a general direction but OpenSSL has an ASN.1 parser.  A quick google also finds asn1parse.  I'm not sure what you mean by "compilers".

Comment: asn1c is a compiler that will generate a C files and then you can write your parser, as I mentioned asn1c is working but not with complicated structures or old ones

Comment: As mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858838/what-does-it-mean-compile-asn-1

Comment: Eight years later, I would ask this on [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 5):

A great place to start is http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/asn1/links/index.htm which list several ASN.1 compilers (both free and commercial).

You can also try your specification in the free online compiler and encoder/decoder at http://asn1-playground.oss.com.

For 3gpp specifications, you are likely to be better off using a commercial tool rather than one of the free tools.  OSS Nokalva offers free trials of its ASN.1 Tools at http://www.oss.com/asn1/products/asn1-download.html.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.itu.int/en/ITU-T/asn1/Pages/Tools.aspx mentions two free ASN.1 compilers, one of which is

- http://lionet.info/asn1c/compiler.html  which is FOSS and seems to be well received (http://lionet.info/asn1c/quotes.html)
- The second “free” compiler listed seems to have gone commercial (http://www.oss.com/asn1/products/asn1-c/asn1-c.html), *BUT* the same company offer a free online encode/decode service at http://asn1-playground.oss.com/
- I can’t figure out if this one is free or requires purchase - http://www.obj-sys.com/products/asn1c/index.php
- This one is FOSS and might be worth examining - https://github.com/ttsiodras/asn1scc

Comment: I've used the one from Objective Systems. It's not free. I was happy with it and their level of support. I think I prefer OSS Nokalva's C++ model though, it's much friendlier to work with than Objective Systems'.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this compiler that works well for generating C code from ASN.1

https://github.com/maxime-esa/asn1scc

There is also a nice introduction that will get you started, here:

https://www.thanassis.space/asn1.html

This is the only compiler that worked for me so far.

EDIT(2023-12-19): I now use https://github.com/nokia/asn1c

Answer (score 1):

Another tool for 3GPP specifications is online encoder/decoder http://3gpp-message-analyser.com It supports UTRAN RANAP SABP RNSAP NBAP PCAP RUA HNBAP, E-UTRAN S1AP X2AP M2AP M3AP

Answer (score 1):

You can  also find various free online ASN.1 decoder here:
https://www.marben-products.com/decoder-asn1/

I hope it helps.
Anto